# Kill event thread generated by lambda expression

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I would like to kill the first thread upon the second click, then re-create it.  My goal is to only ever have one tick thread in existence.

I believe I can do this with supplying a delegate to the thread instance? but I have googled and fiddled with it for hours upon hours with no luck.  Can anyone translate my anonymous lambda expression into something with a delegate so I can identify and kill my thread after I've started it?

I hope my question makes sense, I am still learning... thanks

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
timer1.Interval = 1000;
timer1.Start();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    //If I click button twice, how do I kill the first tick thread,
    //before creating another?
    timer1.Tick += (sender2, e2) => timer1_Tick(sender2, e2, 1, "text");
}


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e, int num, string text)
{
    //do stuff with num and text
}
```

Comment: You're registering to a `Timer.Tick` on every button click. You should register once to it. Why would you want to cancel the previous thread? could you further explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is create a variable to store the delegate -- that should be of type `Action<object, EventArgs>`.  So something like this:

```
private Action<object, EventArgs> _handler;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (_handler != null)
        timer1.Tick -= _handler;
    _handler = (sender2, e2) => timer1_Tick(sender2, e2, 1, "text");
    timer1.Tick += _handler;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e, int num, string text)
{
    timer1.Tick -= _handler;
    _handler = null;
    //do stuff with num and text
}
```

Note that this creates a race condition -- the "_handler" reference could be set to null by a "timer1_Tick" thread *after* the other thread sets the reference, but *before* it adds it to the "Tick" event.  (To avoid the race condition, you would want to create a local copy of "_handler".)  Hopefully that gives you the idea though ...